# Existence of a bounded linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Given a $\phi\in X^*$ and $x\in X$ suppose that there is a $C>0$ such that $|\phi(x)|\leq C|T(x)|$. How to prove that there is a $\psi\in Y^*$ such that $\psi(Tx) = \phi(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $Tx = Ty$ implies $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$. This implies that $\psi_0 : T(X) \to \Bbb{K}, Tx \mapsto \phi(x)$ is well-defined.

Now show that $\psi_0$ is a bounded linear functional and use Hahn-Banach to conclude.

EDIT: Here, I assumed that $C$ is independent of $x,\phi$. If this does not hold, you are probably in trouble.